# How to enlarge size of unwrapped cube from 0 to 1?

Tags: uv

[image]

In uv editing, I make the unwrapped cube size 0 by pressing s, 0.
I want to enlarge the size of unwrapped cube without pressing ctrl, z.
Please somebody help me~

Answer (score 5):

You can't do it in a simple-reverse way, because you lost your information: now all 4 corners sit on the same position in the UV space. So if you can't <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>, *Revert* etc. you have to UV unwrap the cube from scratch; to unwrap it identically to the default cube:

1. Select the right side (<kbd>Numpad 3</kbd> to look at it from the right, though keep in mind if the cube is aligned with the axes, you can just move 3D cursor to it, delete it and create a new cube).
2. <kbd>U</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> to Reset.
3. Select that face in the UV mapping.
4. <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>.</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> (scale it down to 25%)
5. <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>.</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> (then move it up 12.5%)
6. Hover your mouse over the still selected face in the mesh (not UV) and press <kbd>L</kbd> to *select linked*
7. <kbd>U</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> to *Follow Active Quads*.

[image]

If you want to use seams you have to mark 7 seams in this pattern:

[image]

Then rotate the UV 90 degrees clockwise and move 12.5% up like in p. 5 above.

Comment: If it was default Cube you would have to Mark Seams first ... for U twice.

Comment: @vklidu thanks I played around for a bit and found out the U, F method to be the simplest I could come up with. Other than just recreating the cube that is.